# Concatenate string in Linux

Tags: linux

I am new to Linux and I am using command

```
watch "ps u -C appName >> logFile"
```

to obtain the process info of appName and output into logFile.

However, it does not include the date time info.

I know that date command could return the date and time.

How could I insert the date command into the watch statement above so that the date would be included in the logFile for each watch command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Since `watch` takes shell commands, give it a group command.

```
watch "{ date +'...' ; ps u -C appName ; } >> logFile"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like `watch "(date; ps u -C appName >> logFile)"` should work